# What is Scalas Product.productIterator supposed to do?

Tags: scala, product, standard-library

Can someone tell me why I am getting different results when using `Tuple2[List,List]` and `List[List]` as my `Product` in the code below? Specifically I would like to know why the second value of the list of lists gets wrapped in another list?

```
scala> val a = List(1,2,3)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val b = List(4,5,6)
b: List[Int] = List(4, 5, 6)

scala> val c = List(a,b)
c: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6))

scala> c.productIterator.foreach( println(_) )
List(1, 2, 3)
List(List(4, 5, 6)) // <-- Note this

scala> val d = (a,b)
d: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1, 2, 3),List(4, 5, 6))

scala> d.productIterator.foreach( println(_) )
List(1, 2, 3)
List(4, 5, 6) // <-- Compared to this
```

(I have read the (absolutely minimal) description of Scala's Product and the productIterator method on http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Product )

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically, `Tuple` means a product between all of its elements, but a non-empty `List` is a product between its `head` and `tail`.

This happens for `List`, because all `case class`es extend `Product`, and represent a product between all their elements similar to tuples. And non-empty `List` is defined as a case class, containing head and tail: `final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B]`, which inherits the default implementation of `Product` by `case class`.

You can observe more of this behaviour with other `List`s with 1 or more than 2 elements:

```
scala> List(a).productIterator.foreach(println)
List(1, 2, 3)
List()

scala> List(a, a).productIterator.foreach(println)
List(1, 2, 3)
List(List(1, 2, 3))

scala> List(a, a, a).productIterator.foreach(println)
List(1, 2, 3)
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2, 3))
```