# what is use of list productiterator scala

Tags: scala

what is the usecase of productiterator method in List class in scala

```
val l1 = List(1.1, 2.2, 3.3)
val it = l1.productIterator
//I get the following result
res0: Double = 1.1
res1: List[Double] = List(2.2, 3.3)

//but I can get the same using head and tail

l1.head
1.1

l1.tail
List(2.2, 3.3)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Scalas Product.productIterator supposed to do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31137194/what-is-scalas-product-productiterator-supposed-to-do)

Comment: I read this post before posting my question. I didn't find the answer satisfactory. It doesn't explain the use-case. It discusses why the result of productIterator in Tuple is different from that of a List.

Answer (score 3):

There is no specific use case for List's productIterator. List is the `Product` therefore it implements the `Product trait` and I don't see any good use case of `productIterator`. You would certainly prefer to use `list.head`, `list.headOption` or `list.tail`. If you wanted to iterate over the `List`, you can already do that without using the `productIterator`.

Or if you were doing the pattern matching you could use: `h :: t`.

`productIterator` function makes more sense if you wanted to iterate over all elements of the `Tuple` or maybe `case class`, since all `case classes` implement `Product` with synthetically generated methods.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there really is a use case.

Strictly speaking a cons list is a `Product` of either arity 2 or arity 0. Once upon a time it must have seemed a good idea to also reflect that in its type. And `::` is a case class (which always inherits `Product` anyway) for many good reasons, so it makes some sense for `Nil` and `List` to then also be a `Product`.

But the methods that `Product` gives you are not really useful for a `List`. There are better, more idiomatic, alternatives.